# When using Parse.com, how do I create an array from a object in each row in a column within a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

So, I have a class in Parse.com with a few custom columns containing arrays and a column with an int. I am going to be using a `UITableViewController` and will create an `NSArray` for each column from the Parse.com class.

I know how to Retrieve an object, from the great documentation Parse.com has.

But, The problem is, that the way of retrieving that row, from the column, from the class, is if you know the "objectID" number that Parse.com creates. I can not download and populate the array knowing the "objectID" because I won't have the "objectIDs" pre compiled in the app.

So, how do you create an `NSArray` for a object (row) within a certain column in a class using Parse.com?

Comment: You mean how do you query the objects from the server?

Comment: Well kind of, I can already query an object but I need to create an array from a whole column.

Comment: I don't really understand, show an example of the query results and what you want in an array